# Understanding Linux Partition Table

Tags: partitioning, mount

In Windows OS I used to have 2 partitions:

partition #1: Windows OS
partition #2: WorkPlace

Please take a look at my current partition set up:
[image]

```
Partition    | File system   | Mount Point | Flags
===================================================
/dev/sda1    | btrfs         | /           | boot
/dev/sda2    | extended      |             | 
  /dev/sda5  | btrfs         | /home       | 
  /dev/sda6  | linux-swap    |             |
```

Questions:

1. How do I know if all my personal files such as: videos, musics, work docs, php scripts, web templates, etc .... are been saved in sda5/home?
2. How can I make sure Ubuntu is installed on sda1?

Answer (score 2):

## Question 1

It's pretty likely that all the files are in `/home/USERNAME` since it's the default save location for all those. Although an app (or you) may have chosen to save some files elsewhere.

## Question 2

Sure, it's installed at `/dev/sda1` - you can figure that out by looking at the partition setup image you gave, since `/` (the root of the filesystem, where Ubuntu installs to) is mounted at `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: Tks Bharadwaj... after your message I went over /home/username and check to show the hiden files and you are right - all application I have installed was there. My question to you is: what is the best practice to keep ALL linux and installed apps in one partition and have another partition to save your files. I just would like to have the linux and apps separe aside in case of a crash and need restore. hope I make myself clear! Tks.

Comment: The best practice is what you're doing correctly - data/personal files in `/home`, system and apps in `/`

Comment: Separate apps would need a separate `/usr` partition. *I recommend not doing this*. It just adds an extra level of complexity and difficulty to your system with not much real benefit. If you just keep `/home` separate, most of your configuration files will be kept - apps can be reinstalled easily.